# Is it possible to increase the draw distance to more than 15 chunks in Spigot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-spigot

I want to increase the draw distance in Minecraft beyond 15 chunks. A [wiki page](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-configuration/) lists 15 as the max, but I'm wondering whether this has changed and is now possible?

All the solutions I find are obsolete or don't really work.

I want to be able to see far away the horizon and make the world look much more alive!

Comment: You mean the render distance? You can set it to up to 32 chunks on a regular client and arbitrarily high for the server and also for the client, if you edit the settings file. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I forgot to specify for a server!! I want to increase the draw distance to more than 15 chunks! I edited the title and added info :)

Comment: Well, if it explicitly says that it's not possible, how should we answer?

Comment: Because Notch once said that stained glass was impossible and within a few hours someone implemented it ;) You never know if a hacker found a way

Comment: Well, if you mod Spigot itself, of course it's possible. You can also replace Minecraft completely with another game, if you like to. If you include that, then everything that is possible on a computer can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with Spigot!

First, turns out the doc is deprecated, some people had arguments on [this old post](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/bigger-view-distance-than-15.11565/#post-787266) and it seems like an update at some point permitted up to 32 chunks.

One caveat is that if you are using gameserver.com, they are limiting the view distance to 15 chunks in the config file, which is why it wasn't working in the first place as it was being overridden. I found a glitch however and if you set the draw distance to 0 in gameserver's config file then set it to 32 in spigot.yml, it will work!

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted, that way it appears above mine and the question is marked as successfully answered.

Comment: I can in 19 hours ;)